# Depth First Search of graph in Python

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search

Task: Do DFS traversal from a given given graph and print output.

Is this code the correct implementation of DFS traversal in Graph?

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)

    def add_edge(self, u, v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

    def depth_first_search(self,node):
        visited = []
        stack = [node]

        while stack:

            node = stack.pop()
            if node not in visited:
                print node
                visited.append(node)

                for i in self.graph[node]:
                    stack.append(i)



G = Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(1,5)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(3,5)
G.depth_first_search(1)
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior for cyclic graphs? You only have an acyclic graph in your example and DFS struggles with cycles on an arbitrary graph.

Comment: looks good, the only thing to improve is that you could define what node is and based on that you can add hashing algorithm for it. so then instead of having `visited` as `list` you could have it as a `set`. Which will improve your `in` lookup from `O(N)` to `O(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic DFS doesn't use any pruning. That means you should not have a list of `visited` nodes; Hence, my question in the comments. This means that for cyclic graphs DFS does not terminate by default which is why people commonly do pruning on visited nodes; however, revisiting nodes may be wanted, e.g. "list all paths from edge 1 to edge 5". Making the choice of using `visited` not only makes your graph acyclic, but rather "tree-ifys" (technical term ;-) ) it.

---

Assuming `visited` is an okay thing to do you don't want to check `if node not in visited:` after `pop`ing an element but rather before you insert it. It saves you the overhead of appending and popping visited nodes which can be quite substantial.

Further, `visited` should be a `set` (as stated in @Alex 's comment).

It could also be a good idea to use an actual queue object, be that `collections.deque` (for FIFO / LIFO) or a `queue.PriorityQueue`. The latter will slightly reduce performance (insert from O(1) to O(log(queue_size))), but offers *a lot* of added flexibility and easy scalability to graph search.

Setting the priority to: `1/depth` is DFS, `depth` is BFS, `sum(depth)` (or `sum(transition costs)`) is Dijkstra's search, `expected_cost_to_goal` is greedy search, `sum(transition costs) + expected_cost_to_goal` is A*. I think that's a really cool property.